# Accessing JSON elements from javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
$.getJSON('http://23.21.128.153:3000/api/v1/holidays', function(data){
        alert("this: " + data.holiday[0].name);
 });
```

I'm trying to access the "name" attribute of the first element of my JSON response but without success, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Stop guessing, take `console.log(data);` and see what's **actually** in the `data`

Comment: where do i see the logs? in the browser?

Comment: F12 (in chrome) or firebug (in ff), Console tab

Comment: hoi, btw. this will not work, because there is one bracket ) to much. After the name. All the best but thanks for the question

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
data[0].holiday.name
```

The `data` looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "holiday":{
      "id":1,
      "date":"2012-05-01",
      "name":"Dia del trabajo",
      "description":"",
      "country_id":1,
      "moved_date":"2012-04-30"
    }
  },
  {
    "holiday":{...}
  },
...]
```

So, you need to select the first element from the main array (`data[0]`), then get its `holiday` property (`data[0].holiday`), and then get its `name` property.