# Parsing JSON issues

Tags: javascript, json

fairly new to Javascript, but I have been trying to figure out this parsing issue for several days now and I can't seem to put my finger on what is going on.  What I would like to do is get this JSON object into an array or a list of strings into Javascript so that I can use them in my code.

I have a JSON object that I am getting using this URL:

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist
```

So, I am using the following to grab that object from the URL:

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(json){
});
```

to verify that this is indeed a JSON object, I used this which returned "Function Object()"

```
alert(json.constructor);
```

So at this point, I have a JSON object inside the variable "json," I would like to start accessing some of the elements.  So I try the following:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(json.Data));
```

This gives me a popup with all the text from the Data element inside this JSON object, which is great, but I am trying to access the individual items inside "Data."  So I try the following which I found here: [Accessing JSON elements from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842841/accessing-json-elements-from-javascript) :

```
alert(JSON.stringify(json.Data[1])); AND alert(JSON.stringify(json[1].Data));
```

Which gets me an "undefined" response.  I've then tried turning the "Data" part of this Object into it's own object by using the following:

```
var DataObj = JSON.parse(json.Data);
console.log(DataObj["Id"]);
```

But that gives me a "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" error.

So I am not sure how to access this Data.  I have literally been looking for answers for days and I hate to post what I think is a very amateur question on here but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.parse()`, that's done automatically by `$getJSON()`. It returns the object, not JSON.

Comment: `json.Data` is an object. There's no `[1]` property in that object. Try `json.Data[42]`.

Comment: Yea, I figured that out, but how do I access the elements?  I seem to only be able to access the overall data when I stringify, but I am trying to access all the elements under "Data."

Comment: `json.Data[42].CoinName` should work.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I can't believe it took me so long to find such a simple answer.

Comment: "to verify that this is indeed a JSON object, I used this which returned "Function Object()""  No, this is nonsense.  JSON is just a string until you parse it, and then it becomes an object.

Answer (score 0):

json.Data[42].CoinName was an example from Barmar that helped me.  Thank you so much