# ajax returns [object object]

Tags: php, ajax

i am making a quiz webapp with php and ajax where on click of radio button it triggers a function to get the new row in a database using ajax and php however it outputs object object inside the specified div element whenever the ajax success is called.

here is the ajax side of the code:

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){  
           var answer = $(this).val();
           var question_id = $('#dataContainer').data('value');  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"quizengine.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{
                    answer:answer,
                    question_id:question_id
                },
                dataType: 'json',  
                success:function(response){  
                    console.info(response);
                    $('#question').text(response);
                    $('#answer_one').text(response);
                    $('#answer_two').text(response);
                    $('#answer_three').text(response); 
                }  
           });

      });  
 });  

</script>
```

and here is the php side of the code

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "rubiqube";
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
?>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    global $connection;
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        $question_id = $_POST['question_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT is_right FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question_id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (isset($row)) {
            $correct = $row['is_right'];
            if ($answer === $correct) {
                $next = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Questions.question_id,Questions.lesson,Questions.instruction,Questions.question,Questions.image,Questions.option_type,Questions.question_value,Answers.answer_one,Answers.answer_two,Answers.answer_three,Answers.is_right FROM Questions LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.question_id = Answers.question_id WHERE Questions.question_id>'$question_id' ORDER BY Questions.question_id ASC LIMIT 1");

                $nextrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($next);
                echo json_encode($nextrow);
                exit();
            }else{
                echo "error";
                exit();
            }
        }

    }




?>
```

here is an image of what i am talking about
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhKFo.png)

Comment: JSON == JavaScript OBJECT Notation.  What exactly are you _expecting_ to get?  If you want a specific element in the object, then you have to access that specific element.

Comment: i want when the ajax retrieve the row it output the value in text format to the divs with id of #question, #answer_one etc

Comment: Well that's not just going to magically happen.  You have to create the output exactly how you want it.  There are plenty of questions/answers here about how to access JSON elements with JavaScript.  Ones like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842841/accessing-json-elements-from-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910939/how-to-get-json-key-and-value-in-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297161/how-to-access-elements-of-json-array-using-javascript-jquery might be a good place to start

Comment: okay thank you i will try out these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the response comes back in the success callback, `dataType: 'json'` will convert it from json to an object (thus why you're seeing [object object]). You can't use the `.text()` method on it directly as that requires it to be a string. You may be able to do `$('#question').text(response.key)` depending on the data structure.

You need to simply either loop through the object and use the data, or access the properties directly (i.e. `console.log(response.key)`).

Here is some documentation from MDN on what to do with an object. [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the Question on the server'side, then in your ajax response do this:

```
success:function(response){

                $('#question').text(response.propertyName);
                //propertyNamerefers to the one you made on the serverside
            }
```

Comment: This isn't needed. He has `dataType: 'json'` which automatically parses it.